# Download and store webpages from server, run locally

Tags: store, html, local

I am writing a mobile app (HTML5/JavaScript)  that has several functions that do not need a server contact. Basically I would like to download all pages from the server and keep them in HTML5 Local Store. If Server is available I will check for updates to web pages and download. 
Two advantages. Some functionality when "offline" and "automatic" SW updates.
Questions:
1. Is it workable?
2. What "components/functionality" to build on?

Comment: Talking about caching?

Comment: Well, that was anal, I know what you meant...